# Error Identification from batch file in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, error-handling, azure-devops

Can you suggest a way to identify error that comes from batch file in Powershell command prompt.I'm using Azure here.
I have embedded a batch file in Powershell script. This batch file requires username  & password.When I give wrong username or password, the Powershell prompt says there is Authentication Error. Yet it doesn't show it different color and is misleading.

```
Test.ps1

$command = "C:/DeployScripts/TestBatch.bat"
Invoke-Expression $command
```

This is the batchfile called from Test.ps1

```
TestBatch.bat

"C:\clearlocks.exe" -u= -p=password
```

You can see I did not give the user name. So when running the powershell script,
it gave an error

```
2019-10-14T06:51:00.8038792Z You are not a privileged User to run clearlocks
```

This error was displayed in plain white text in powershell prompt. I want to store this error in a variable and give a different color(say red) so as to differentiate as an error.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and add more details. Copy and paste the error you are getting and relevant parts of batch and Powershell scripts for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Logging Commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) is what you looking for.

[image]